# How to apply multiple data validation rules in a cell by google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to apply two data validation rules in a cell, but it seems to not be working.
I am not sure if it supports multi-rules for data validation.

```html
function validateMySpreadsheet2() {
  // Set a rule for the cell B4 to be a number between 1 and 100.
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C2');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()

    .requireValueInList(['Yes@ff.com', 'No@cc.com'], true)
    .setAllowInvalid(true)
    .requireTextIsEmail()
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .setHelpText('It should be Email.');

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: Does [tag:google-sheet] support multiple datavalidations in cell through UI?

Comment: why do you need to use App-Script? You can do this using the Data Validation UI directly

Comment: data validation UI can only apply one rule in a cell:(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this issue with if function.
I read the cell and validate it by my function instead of built-in function.
The disadvantage is performance is a little bit slow.